# Combining blocking and non-blocking retries in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to implement non blocking retries with single topic fixed back-off.

I am able to do so, thanks to documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#single-topic-fixed-delay-retries.

Now I also need to perform a few blocked/local retries on main topic. I have been trying to implement this using `DefaultErrorHandler` as below:

```
@Bean
public DefaultErrorHandler retryErrorHandler() {
        return new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(2000, 3));
}
```

This does not seem to work with `RetryableTopic`.

I have also tried the following approach `retry-topic-combine-blocking` https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-combine-blocking using `ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer`
but issue I am facing here is creating beans `KafkaConsumerBackoffManager`, `DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory` and especially `KafkaConsumerBackoffManager`.

I need to know if this another way to achieve this using spring kafka framework or is there a way to construct above beans ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're currently working on improving configuration for the non-blocking retries components.

For now, as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-combine-blocking), you should inject these beans such as:

```java
@Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_CONFIGURER_NAME)
public ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer lcfc(KafkaConsumerBackoffManager kafkaConsumerBackoffManager,
                                               DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory,
                                               @Qualifier(RetryTopicInternalBeanNames
                                                       .INTERNAL_BACKOFF_CLOCK_BEAN_NAME) Clock clock) {
    ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer lcfc = new ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer(kafkaConsumerBackoffManager, deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory, clock);
    lcfc.setBlockingRetryableExceptions(MyBlockingRetryException.class, MyOtherBlockingRetryException.class);
    lcfc.setBlockingRetriesBackOff(new FixedBackOff(500, 5)); // Optional
    return lcfc;
}}
```

Also, there's a known issue where if you try to inject the beans before the first `@KafkaListener` bean with retryable topic is processed, the feature's component's beans won't be present in the context yet and will throw an error.

Does that happen to you?

We're currently working on a [fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2174) for this, but we should be able to work around that if that's your problem.

EDIT: Since the problem is that components are not instantiated yet, the most guaranteed workaround is to provide the components yourself.

Here's a sample on how to do that. Of course, adjust it accordingly if you need any further customization.

```java
    @Configuration
    public static class SO71705876Configuration {

        @Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_CONFIGURER_NAME)
        public ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer lcfc(KafkaConsumerBackoffManager kafkaConsumerBackoffManager,
                DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory) {
            ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer lcfc = new ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer(kafkaConsumerBackoffManager, deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory, Clock.systemUTC());
            lcfc.setBlockingRetryableExceptions(IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class);
            lcfc.setBlockingRetriesBackOff(new FixedBackOff(500, 5)); // Optional
            return lcfc;
        }

        @Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.KAFKA_CONSUMER_BACKOFF_MANAGER)
        public KafkaConsumerBackoffManager backOffManager(ApplicationContext context) {
            PartitionPausingBackOffManagerFactory managerFactory =
                    new PartitionPausingBackOffManagerFactory();
            managerFactory.setApplicationContext(context);
            return managerFactory.create();
        }

        @Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.DEAD_LETTER_PUBLISHING_RECOVERER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
        public DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory dlprFactory(DestinationTopicResolver resolver) {
            return new DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory(resolver);
        }

        @Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.DESTINATION_TOPIC_CONTAINER_NAME)
        public DestinationTopicResolver destinationTopicResolver(ApplicationContext context) {
            return new DefaultDestinationTopicResolver(Clock.systemUTC(), context);
        }
```

In the next release this should not be a problem anymore. Please let me know if that works for you, or if any further adjustment to this workaround is necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes exactly, beans doesn't seem to be present in context for autowiring. Is there a work around for that ?

Comment: I edited the answer with the workaround. Please let me know if that works for you or if any further adjustments are necessary. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited a couple things in the workaround.

Comment: @AshishSingh, did that work for you? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that works, thank you very much. Still waiting for fix though.

Comment: Glad it worked, thanks for letting us know. We’re actively working on the fix and hopefully it’ll be ready in 2.8.5 which is out in a couple of weeks.