# BackoffExceptions are logged at error level when using RetryTopicConfiguration

Tags: spring-kafka

I am a happy user of the recently added `RetryTopicConfiguration` there is however a small issue that is bothering me.
The setup I use looks like:

```
@Bean
public RetryTopicConfiguration retryTopicConfiguration(
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> template,
    @Value("${kafka.topic.in}") String topicToInclude,
    @Value("${spring.application.name}") String appName) {
    return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
        .newInstance()
        .fixedBackOff(5000L)
        .maxAttempts(3)
        .retryTopicSuffix("-" + appName + ".retry")
        .suffixTopicsWithIndexValues()
        .dltSuffix("-" + appName + ".dlq")
        .includeTopic(topicToInclude)
        .dltHandlerMethod(KAFKA_EVENT_LISTENER, "handleDltEvent")
        .create(template);
}
```

When the a listener throws an exception that triggers a retry, the `DefaultErrorHandler` will log a `KafkaBackoffException` at error level.

For a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706953/7605085) it was suggested to use a `ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` yet this does not remove all error logs, since I still see the following in my logs:

```
2022-04-02 17:34:33.340 ERROR 8054 --- [e.retry-0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler   : Recovery of record (topic-spring-kafka-logging-issue.retry-0-0@0) failed

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaBackoffException: Partition 0 from topic topic-spring-kafka-logging-issue.retry-0 is not ready for consumption, backing off for approx. 4468 millis.
```

Can the log-level be changed, without adding a custom `ErrorHandler`?

Spring-Boot version: 2.6.6
Spring-Kafka version: 2.8.4
JDK version: 11

Sample project: [here](https://github.com/tzie0062/spring-kafka-logging-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for such a complete question. This is a known issue of Spring for Apache Kafka `2.8.4` due to the new [combine blocking and non-blocking exceptions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-combine-blocking) feature and has been fixed for `2.8.5`.

The workaround is to clear the blocking exceptions mechanism such as:

```java
@Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_CONFIGURER_NAME)
public ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer lcfc(KafkaConsumerBackoffManager kafkaConsumerBackoffManager,
                        DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory,
                        @Qualifier(RetryTopicInternalBeanNames
                            .INTERNAL_BACKOFF_CLOCK_BEAN_NAME) Clock clock) {
    ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer lcfc = new ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer(kafkaConsumerBackoffManager, deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory, clock);

    lcfc.setBlockingRetriesBackOff(new FixedBackOff(0, 0));
    lcfc.setErrorHandlerCustomizer(eh -> ((DefaultErrorHandler) eh).setClassifications(Collections.emptyMap(), true));
    return lcfc;
}
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

Thanks.

EDIT:
This workaround disables only `blocking retries`, which since 2.8.4 can be used along `non-blocking` as per the link in the original answer. The exception classification for the `non-blocking retries` is in the `DefaultDestinationTopicResolver` class, and you can set `FATAL` exceptions as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-ex-classifier).

EDIT: <s>Alternatively, you can use the Spring Kafka `2.8.5-SNAPSHOT` version by adding the Spring Snapshot repository such as:</s>

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.8.5-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

You can also downgrade to `Spring Kafka 2.8.3`.

As Gary Russell pointed out, if your application is already in production you should not use the `SNAPSHOT` version, and `2.8.5` is out [in a couple of weeks](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/milestone/180).

EDIT 2: Glad to hear you’re happy about the feature!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Adding 
`lcfc.setErrorHandlerCustomizer(eh -> ((DefaultErrorHandler) eh).setClassifications(Collections.emptyMap(), true));`
helped to remove the `ERROR` logs, however I wonder whether this causes any other side-effects. IIRC, calling `setClassifications()` will remove the exceptions that are skipped by default, right?
Also, the exception triggering the retries is never logged. Should this rather be handled by the application?

Comment: It would not be good practice to use SNAPSHOT builds in production. 2.8.5 will be released in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Gary, edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Also, @LorenzoVonMatterhorn, I've edited the answer with the answer to your question about exception classification. Not sure about the logging - it should be logged normally when the exception is not a `KafkaBackOffException`.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn, I opened a [discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2211) on GitHub regarding the lack of logging when the record goes through the `Retry Topic` flow. Feel free to pitch in if you have anything to add. From there we can open an issue and have a fix for this. Thanks.