# When @RetryableTopic annotation is used, SerializationException exception is not handled

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have configured RetryableTopic annotation and it is working as expected but

Also, I have configured setCommonErrorHandler for handling the SerializationException exception to seek the offset, but it is not working.

If remove the RetryableTopic annotation, The SerializationException is handled but not with RetryableTopic annotation.

Below is the code for reference,

```
@RetryableTopic(attempts = "3", backoff = @Backoff(delay = 120000, multiplier
= 2.0), autoCreateTopics = "false", topicSuffixingStrategy =
TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{kafkaProperties.getTopic()}", groupId = "#{kafkaProperties.getGroupId()}")
public void handleMessage(Message message) {

}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConsumerFactory<String, Message> consumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency(kafkaProperties.getConcurrency());
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new KafkaConsumptionErrHandler());
    return factory;
}

public class KafkaConsumptionErrHandler extends CommonLoggingErrorHandler {

    private void seekSerializeException(Exception e, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        String p = ".*partition (.*) at offset ([0-9]*).*";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(p);

        Matcher m = r.matcher(e.getMessage());

        if (m.find()) {
            int idx = m.group(1).lastIndexOf("-");
            String topics = m.group(1).substring(0, idx);
            int partition = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1).substring(idx + 1));
            int offset = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
            TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topics, partition);
            consumer.seek(topicPartition, (offset + 1));
            log.info("Skipped message, with offset {} from partition {}", offset, partition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleOtherException(Exception e, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container,
            boolean batchListener) {
        log.error(">>> Error in process with Exception {}", e.getMessage());

        if (e instanceof SerializationException)
            seekSerializeException(e, consumer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RetryableTopic` feature creates and configures it's own `DefaultErrorHandler` in order to be able to properly configure the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` that forwards records to the retry topics.

It's not compatible with `CommonLoggingErrorHandler`, but you can provide your own `DefaultErrorHandler` subclass by overriding the `createDefaultErrorHandlerInstance` method in a `ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` bean, such as:

```java
        @Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_CONFIGURER_NAME)
        ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer listenerContainerFactoryConfigurer(KafkaConsumerBackoffManager kafkaConsumerBackoffManager,
                                                                              DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory) {
            return new ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer(kafkaConsumerBackoffManager, deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory, Clock.systemUTC()) {
                @Override
                protected DefaultErrorHandler createDefaultErrorHandlerInstance(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer) {
                    return new MyDefaultErrorHandlerSubClass(deadLetterPublishingRecoverer);
                }
            };
        }
```

If you get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, refer to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705876/combining-blocking-and-non-blocking-retries-in-spring-kafka/71706953#71706953) for a workaround. We're currently working on a fix for that - not sure when it'll be available though.